# Using VLOOKUP to match a password with a user

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have two Excel worksheets in the same file.

One is a full list of Parents and their associated children.

The other is a list of Parents and their platform logins.

**For some reason, I have a discrepancy in length between the two files - i.e. there is 570 users in one file and 599 in the other**.

What I'd like to do is - presumably using `VLOOKUP` - display the parents' passwords if their usernames match on both sheets.

**Sheet one** (called **ParentChildren**)

`ParentUniqueID` `ParentTitle` `ParentForename` `ParentSurname` `ParentUsername`   `Password` `ChildForename` `ChildSurname` `ChildYeargroup` `ChildRegGroup` `ChildUniqueID`

**Sheet two** (called **ParentLogins**)

`Surname` `Forename` `Login Profile` `UID` `Username` `Password`

**What I'd like to do...**

If `ParentUsername` in *!ParentChildren* matches `Username` in *!ParentLogins*, fill the `Password` field on *!ParentChildren* (which is currently empty) with the data from the corresponding `Password` field on *!ParentLogins*.

If a row doesn't match - i.e. there's a username which exists in *!ParentChildren* but not *!ParentLogins*, I'd like that row's `Password` field in *!ParentChildren* to remain empty.

Hope that makes sense - think I've somewhat confused myself!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried VLOOPKUP yet? What results did you get, if any?

Comment: I haven't, no. I can't get my head round I'd use a VLOOKUP in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas are much easier to write if the data is in a table (Excel 2007 and later) so I've written the formula like that.

So the `Password` cell in **ParentChildren** would be the formula:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@ParentUsername], ParentLogins, 6, FALSE), "")`

Give that a shot and let me know if it does what you're looking for. This assumes you're using Excel 2007 or higher, if you're not let me know as it's not too hard to tweak the formula.